# On Handsontable how can I disable the 'edit' action on updating a cell by 'setDataAtCell' inside from 'copyPaste' event

Tags: handsontable

I am using Handsontable spreadsheet control with php and data saved in mongodb.
When copy paste a bunch of data on control, 'afterChage' event triggers with source as 'paste'. Inside this i am trying to update a value (RowID) on a particular cell (0) using the function instance.setDataAtCell(rowIndex, 0, vRowId)

```
 afterChange: function(changes, source) {

   console.log('Trigrd>>');
   console.log('Source:'+source);
   console.log('Changes:'+changes);
   if (source  == 'paste' || source  == 'autofill' || (changes.length >1 )) {
     var minVal            = changes[0][0];
     var maxVal            = changes[chLength][0];

     for(var modifyRowIndex = minVal; modifyRowIndex <= maxVal ;modifyRowIndex++){
        var xrowId          = Math.random();
        instance.setDataAtCell(modifyRowIndex, 0, xrowId, 'program');
     }
   }

 }
```

if i try to paste two row data on spreadsheet, on console we can see that the afterChange function is triggered 3 times.

```
Trigrd>>
Source:paste
Changes:[[0,1,'','xxxx'],[1,1,'','yyyy']]
Trigrd>>
Source:edit
Changes:[0,0,'','1232']
Trigrd>>
Source:edit
Changes:[1,0,'','23434']
```

The first trigger is for the action 'paste' and remaining two trigger is due to the command 'setDataAtCell'. This makes a delay on total copyPaste action. Some times it stuck with large data copyPaste

Anybody have any idea to skip the 'edit' loop here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are still looking for a solution I think this one will help you.

I had a problem like yours and I managed to resolve it by making modifications on `beforeChange` and not in `afterChange`:

```
beforeChange : function(changes, source){
    if (source  == 'paste'){
        var nrChanges = changes.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < nrChanges; i++)
            if (changes[i][1] == _CB) // get cell where you want to control
                changes[i][3] = false; // here you add your value
    }
}
```

and on `afterChange` you will get the values you set it ...

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I already solved the issue using the same method which you mentioned here  'beforeChange'.  :)